# C++ Read/write data with user-define object

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

I'm beginner with C++ and I have code like this

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Role
{
public:
    Role(int r, bool x)
        :role(r), active(x)
    {}
private:
    int role;
    bool active;
};
class Test
{
public:
    Test(vector<Role> xxxx = {})
        :xxx(xxxx)
    {}    
private:
    std::vector<Role> xxx;
};
int main()
{
    vector<Role> role = { Role(1,true),Role(2,false),Role(3, true) };
    Test test1(role);
    fstream dataTransfer("data.txt");
    Test test2;
    dataTransfer.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&test1), sizeof(Test));
    dataTransfer.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&test2), sizeof(Test));    // error
    return 0;
}
```

This code cause "Read access violation" but i can't find any error.
Thank for any help

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char*>` is a _terrible_, __terrible__ way to serialise an object.

Comment: `sizeof(Test)` is a ***compile time constant*** that gives the size of of the `Test` structure in bytes. You will be shocked to learn that the size of the structure is the same whether its `xxx` member, a vector, contains one value, or a million. You should obviously understand that it makes no sense to try to write the same number of bytes to your file, whether the vector has one value, or a million. After thinking about this, your bug should become very obvious to you.

Comment: You declare an object without calling the constructor you have defined by `Test test2;`

Comment: Thanks for your help @SamVarshavchik. How can i write/read file in this case ?

Comment: You will need to write your own serialization function, that writes the number of elements of the vector into the file first, then the contents of the vector.

Comment: I ran the code with no problems. Do you have anything already existing in the `data.txt` and if yes could you provide it?

Comment: I just create empty file 'data.txt' and it still error